# Pushing number using Splice() method through function

Tags: javascript

I've tried to push a number according to it's position following higher order.But the output shows undefined!

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    // Find my place in this sorted array.
    arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]>=num){
            return arr.splice(i,0,num);
        }
    }
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50));//Expected output:[40,50,60];
```

Kindly fix the problem so it is throws the expected array..
Thanks..
Expected Output:[40,50,60];

Comment: Why not just add the new value at the end and then sort the array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the array after splicing, not the taken array of the deleted items ([`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)).

Then you need to take care of greater items than the last one and push this value (to the end of the array).

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    if (num >= arr[arr.length - 1]) {
        arr.push(num);
        return arr;  
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > num) {
            arr.splice(i, 0, num);
            return arr;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(...getIndexToIns([40, 60], 40)); // [40, 40, 60]
console.log(...getIndexToIns([40, 60], 60)); // [40, 60, 60]
console.log(...getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50)); // [40, 50, 60]
console.log(...getIndexToIns([40, 60], 20)); // [20, 40, 60]
console.log(...getIndexToIns([40, 60], 90)); // [40, 60, 90]
```